# K Nearest Neighbor running-mean smoother

Tags: nonparametric, pattern-recognition, k-nearest-neighbour

I am implementing a k-nearest neighbors [KNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithmprediction) algorithm for a very simple question to see how it works. In textbooks it is mentioned like this:

Suppose we have generated $10$ at random with $Y = \sin(4*X) + \epsilon$ with $X \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1/3)$. Now a test set includes

$X.TEST =  cbind(seq(0.1,1,0.1))$

When I do

$knn.predTest = knn(train = X.TRAIN , test = X.TEST , Y , k = 3)$

It should find for a test point $(x, y)$, the estimate $\hat{y} = \left(\sum_{i \in N_3(x)}x_i\right)/3$ but the plots do not show that. I have put the code here:

```
    X <- runif(10)
    LENGTH.X <- length(X)
    EPSILON <- rnorm(n = LENGTH.X , mean = 0 , sd = 1/3)
    Y <- sin(4*X) + EPSILON

    X.TEST <- cbind(seq(0.1,1,0.1))
    Y.TEST <- sin(4*as.numeric(X.TEST)) + EPSILON
    X.TRAIN <- cbind(X)

    knn.predTest <- knn(train = X.TRAIN , test = X.TEST , Y , k = 3)

    # Check test error rate
    mean((as.numeric(paste(knn.predTest)) - Y.TEST) < 0.01)

    # Plots the training data points and test data predicted
    plot(X , Y , pch = "+" , xlim = c(0,1))
    points(X.TEST , as.numeric(paste(knn.predTest)) , col = "red")
```

For example, I ran it and got this plot:

[image: Data points with + sign and predicted points of X.TEST with red circles]

It is clear that the $\hat{y}$ for $x = 0.1$ (the red circle), should be the average of $y$s at $0$, $0.02$, and $3.6$ but it does not seem to be their average, does it? (Unless I am making some silly mistake)

The other important question is, if one runs the line,

```
    knn.predTest <- knn(train = X.TRAIN , test = X.TEST , Y , k = 3)
```

several times, can notice that each time the plots change but with test and train data fixed, isn't it supposed to produce the same prediction every time?

Comment: The goal is to replicate Figure 6.1 in "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani, et al. Hope this helps.